# Simpletest db table cleanup

Tags: 7, testing

Everytime I run simpletest it creates tables that it does not clean up.  Is there anyway to tell drupal to automatically clean these? I looked in my db today and there are hundred of misc unecessary simpletest tables.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That only happens when the test is aborted (e.g. fatal error inside the test class) so that Simpletest isn't able to do the cleanup.

There is a button called "Clean environment" at the bottom of the test overview page and a message telling you about that button when a test is aborted.

[image: screenshot]